# How can i fix: Tried resolving a template file for controller action "Page->emptySide" in format ".html"?

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

after the Upgrade to TYPO3 11, i get the following error in the backend.

`Tried resolving a template file for controller action "Page->emptySide" in format ".html", but none of the paths contained the expected template file (). The following paths were checked: /var/www/html/web/typo3conf/ext/my_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/`

The system is working properly. Frontend is completely correct.

I tried to add the missing Template file. When i do this, i get the error for missing configuration in the template.